# React production build blank page with error

Tags: reactjs

I've built my blog using React and it worked fine in development mode, but it appeared blank page in the production build with an error if I upload it to Netlify.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (utils.js:48)
at f (index.html:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (URL.js:4)
at f (index.html:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (webidl2js-wrapper.js:3)
at f (index.html:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
at f (index.html:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (api.js:7)
```

I deleted the whole src and public folder at the beginning, is that the reason since I use the same method to upload my other react projects and it worked as intended.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.2.6",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "marked": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

If no running code in production mode. So first of all build your project on development then deploy on server. But only deploy build project